# Retrieving SQL row and set to string

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

I'm somewhat new to C# - I have a connection string set in my app web.config called "ApplicationServices"  Using C#, how can I write a certain SQL command that retrieves data from my database and set's it to a string that I can operate on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the full explanation.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx

```
//Taken from MSDN
private static void ReadOrderData(string connectionString)
{
    string queryString =
        "SELECT OrderID, CustomerID FROM dbo.Orders;";
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(
            queryString, connection);
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        try
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}, {1}",
                    reader[0], reader[1]));
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            // Always call Close when done reading.
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

You can also use an ORM such as LINQ2SQL 
http://codesamplez.com/database/linq-to-sql-c-sharp-tutorial

**EDIT:**

How to debug...

Below are some links on how to use the debugging features in visual studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165053.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0k771bt(v=vs.71).aspx
http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging

Comment: I tried the MSDN method here replacing with my own connection string and SQL query, but I don't see anything being written to the console.  What's the best way to go about debugging this?

Comment: Are you sure your SQL query is returning records? Try Writing `reader.HasRows` to the output also try removing the try/finally statements, this will allow the Console to throw any errors.  Otherwise look at my edit in my answer there is  tutorials on debuging

Comment: Looks like I had my table name incorrect in my SQL query - looks like it's working now.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for first pointing to ADO.NET and not immediately pushing a newbie toward an ORM, where the learning curve is way steeper!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning on writing a query that returns one single value, you should have a look at **ExecuteScalar**. See this example for a quick demo on how to retrieve a value from the database and set it to a variable:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx